# await / async with Vs2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asynchronous, async-await

I am currently working on a project in WPF Windows Vista. I have VS2010 and .Net 4.0. My question is as follows. knowing that I can install the `.Net Framework 4.5`, but imposssible install `VS2012 (or 2013)` on Vista. Are there any way to use the keys on words: `async` / `await` with Vs2010`?

Comment: indeed, the response of @Xiaomin is very relevant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/tags/async-await/info

"Async CTP add-on for VS2010 SP1 is also available, but it is not suitable for production development."

Comment: If you could develop more